# What the best possible way to concatenate pandas column? From a list of column

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I have dataframe like this:

```
A     B     C    D     E      F
aa    bb    cc  dd    ee      ff
NA    ba    NA  da    ea      NA

list_col = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

So i just want to merge the columns which are in list only. Moreover i dont want NA values as merged..  is there any way?

desired_output

```
 A     B     C    D     E      F         desired_col
aa    bb    cc  dd    ee      ff          aa-bb-cc
NA    ba    NA  da    ea      NA             ba
```

Comment: You can use something like `df = df[list_col]`. It's not clear what you mean by not wanting "NA values as merged".

Comment: does `df.reindex(columns=list_col)` do what you want?

Comment: No i just want to merge all the column in one column which are in list... So mainly i want  new column which is result of all merged columns.

Comment: maybe you can desired output?

Comment: I edited in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply(..., x=1)` to process a dataframe row wise. But you want to ignore NaN values, so you will have to exclude them. You could use:

```
df[list_col].apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
```

It gives:

```
0    aa-bb-cc
1          ba
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a comprehension list :

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff'), (None, 'ba', None, 'da', 'ea', None),],
    columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
 )

desired_col = ['A', 'B', 'C']

def join_values(values):
    return '-'.join(map(str, values)) if values else None


df['desired_col'] = [
    join_values(filter(lambda v : not pd.isnull(v), values))
    for values in zip(*(df[c] for c in desired_col))        
]
df
      A   B     C   D   E     F desired_col
0    aa  bb    cc  dd  ee    ff    aa-bb-cc
1  None  ba  None  da  ea  None          ba
```

Note that if your NA values are strings `"NA"`, you can simply replace the filtering function :

```py
df['desired_col'] = [
    join_values(filter(lambda v : v != 'NA', values))
    for values in zip(*(df[c] for c in desired_col))        
]
```

Comment: I tried this before but didnt able to solve this `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found`

Comment: Still getting the same error.... `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found`

Comment: I assumed you had string values inside your columns but it appears you have float values. I changed my answer